# Is it possible to add custom bl_info addon attributes that show up in the Preferences popup?

Tags: python, add-on

I have an addon that uses a third party binary and I want to include this information for the user to see. I want to add another type of info to the users in the area marked in yellow but when I add this custom `included_binary_version` attribute in the `bl_info` object, it doesn't show up.

[image]

This is the `bl_info` block in the `__init__.py` file but `included_binary_version` does not show up in the yellow marked area. I know the supported attributes are in the [documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo), but I was wondering if there is a way to make additional attributes show up? Or is this not possible? Or some hack I can use?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Addon Name",
    "description": "",
    "author" : "Harry McKenzie",
    "version": (1, 0, 4),
    "blender": (2, 93, 0),
    "included_binary_version": (1, 2, 5),
    "location": "File >",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "category": "Import-Export",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That UI is drawn by [this code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/9c0bffcc89f174f160805de042b00ae7c201c40b/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_userpref.py#L2230-L2306), which hardcodes the list of properties that appear there, so the straight-forward answer is "no".

Comment: oh no.. so what do you think is the best way i can communicate to the user about the version of the binary included in my addon?

Comment: Put it in the description?

Comment: right! guess i have no choice haha thank you!